# kernel messages about failed to assign mem

Tags: rhel, kernel, crash, dmesg, hang

we have 5 Linux rhel machines , 
we noticed that all machines was hang with the same time

from messages file we can se the following

```
Dec 29 19:54:25 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Dec 29 19:54:25 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
```

is this kernel messages are maybe the reason for linux crash/hang?

according to redhat , they recommended to update the kernel version ( https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2772311 )

but they not mention anything about linux crash/hang

Comment: That page is for RHEL7. Which is a product currently supported. RHEL5 went end of life years ago. I doubt you’ll get much help with its kernel.

Comment: yes its rhel 7 .........